# Predictable Processes for a constant

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Hi, Just a quick question:

-Is a constant for example 2 always a predictable process for the natural $\sigma$-algebra ?

Then let say your filtration $\mathcal{F}_n$ with $n$ is from 0...n is 1/n measurable on $\mathcal{F}_{n-1}$?

We know that E[1/n]=1/n so it should be measurable on F0 ? so on Fn-1..

Thank's a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Yes any constant is $\mathcal{F}_0$ measurable and hence $X_n=cte\in \mathcal{F}_0 \subset \mathcal{F}_{n-1}$ is a predicable process.

Regarding your example the same argument applies but this time to a deterministic process $X_n=a_n \in \mathcal{F}_0 \subset \mathcal{F}_{n-1}$ instead of a constant process.

Best regards